# Scaling down webpage on mobile causes rows to offset

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, mobile

I am using Bootstrap on a webpage and am having problems with the rows scaling down to mobile.

The intended effect is for rows separated into 4 equal parts per row scale down to 2 equal divisions per row on Mobile Devices. This works well except for when the device goes below a certain width (approximately 335 px). Below that threshold, the rows get all messed up in some areas where the divisions are not horizontally aligned any longer.

Here is [a link to the page](http://www.texasca.com/team) so you can see what I mean.

- Keep in mind the problem is only on a very small screen size so you will have to shrink your browser window down to < 335px in width.

What exactly is causing this? And how do you think it can be fixed?

- For the HTML & CSS please follow the link to www.texasca.com/team.html

The markup and CSS seem to complicated/long to actually put into the question, but let me know if you want me to and I will do so.

Here is an image of the problem:

[image: Rows are offset in this image -- when they are supposed to be lined up]

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a float clearing issue. Try adding Bootstraps "clearfix" class to your divs. You can get more information about this issue here http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-responsive-resets.

Comment: Wow, it was really that simple. Thanks